# How do I calculate the reflection vector?

Tags: math, vector, reflection, calculation

How do I calculate the reflection vector of this problem? I know from looking at it that the reflection vector is meant to be `R(1, 0)` but I dont understand how to get there. I have looked everywhere and every time this formula keeps coming up `r = v−2(v⋅n)n`. I have tried this and it doesn't give me the answer I'm looking for. Any help with this would be appreciated and please include the steps of the solution.

[image: Problem]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Try [math.se] instead.

Comment: Also, be more specific about your attempts. Show what you have tried. The formula should work once you have the correct normal. And I think one of `A`/`B` is missing a `-` in the `y` coordinate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find reflection vector when the object doesn't sit on an axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58699100/how-to-find-reflection-vector-when-the-object-doesnt-sit-on-an-axis)