# How to find reflection vector when the object doesn't sit on an axis?

Tags: math, vector, reflection, angle, calculation

How do I calculate the reflection vector to this problem? Using the formula r = v - 2 (v.n)n I can get the reflection when the object is sat on the x or y axis however when using this formula when it isnt seems to give strange results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0t5W.jpg)

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically? If not, this question would be better suited to Math SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal vector `n` needs to be normalized.

In your example, `n` should be `(1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2))`.

Comment: I appreciate this more than you know